# When drawing a rectangle in a pictureBox control if moving the mouse cursor too fast sometimes it will lost focus of the drawn rectangle. how to fix?

Tags: c#, winforms

The problem is if I try to draw the rectangle very fast when moving the mouse around in the pictureBox area. Then when the mouse is leaving the pictureBox area instead it will draw the rectangle until the pictureBox edge of the direction I moved the mouse cursor it stop somewhere in the middle.  it does draw the rectangle but not the size it should be because I'm moving the mouse very fast.

Is there any way to work around it?

mouse down event:

```
private void pictureBoxImageToCrop_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left || crop == false) return;

    x = 0;
    y = 0;

    if (pictureBoxImageToCrop.Image != null && selectedPath != null)
    {
        if (!isRealTimeCropping)
        {
            if ((x >= 0 && x <= pictureBoxImageToCrop.Image.Size.Width) && (y >= 0 && y <= pictureBoxImageToCrop.Image.Size.Height))
            {
                DrawingRects.Add(new DrawingRectangle()
                {
                    Location = e.Location,
                    Size = Size.Empty,
                    StartPosition = e.Location,
                    Owner = (Control)sender,
                    DrawingcColor = SelectedColor
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBoxCroppedImages.Image = null;
        }
    }
}
```

mouse move event:

```
private void pictureBoxImageToCrop_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int X = e.X;
    int Y = e.Y;

    label1.Text = X.ToString() + " - " + Y.ToString();

    if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left || crop == false) return;

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
    }
    else
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }

    if (!isRealTimeCropping)
    {
        if ((X >= 0 && X <= pictureBoxImageToCrop.Width) && (Y >= 0 && Y <= pictureBoxImageToCrop.Height))
        {
            if (pictureBoxImageToCrop.Image != null && selectedPath != null && DrawingRects.Count > 0)
            {
                if ((x >= 0 && x <= pictureBoxImageToCrop.Image.Size.Width) && (y >= 0 && y <= pictureBoxImageToCrop.Image.Size.Height))
                {
                    x = e.X;
                    y = e.Y;

                    var dr = DrawingRects[DrawingRects.Count - 1];
                    if (e.Y < dr.StartPosition.Y) { dr.Location = new Point(dr.Rect.Location.X, e.Y); }
                    if (e.X < dr.StartPosition.X) { dr.Location = new Point(e.X, dr.Rect.Location.Y); }

                    dr.Size = new Size(Math.Abs(dr.StartPosition.X - e.X), Math.Abs(dr.StartPosition.Y - e.Y));
                    pictureBoxImageToCrop.Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (isRealTimeCropping)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
        realTimeCursorPos = new Point(e.X - cropRectWidth / 2, e.Y - cropRectHeight / 2);
        Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(realTimeCursorPos.X, realTimeCursorPos.Y, cropRectWidth, cropRectHeight);
        realTimeCroppedImage = cropAtRect((Bitmap)pictureBoxImageToCrop.Image, cropRect); // Set realTimeCroppedImage instead of pictureBoxCroppedImages.Image
        pictureBoxCroppedImages.Invalidate(); // refresh the whole picture box
    }
    else
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

mouse up event:

```
int count = 0;
private void pictureBoxImageToCrop_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left || crop == false) return;

    if (DrawingRects.Count > 0 && pictureBoxImageToCrop.Image != null && selectedPath != "")
    {
        if ((x >= 0 && x <= pictureBoxImageToCrop.Image.Size.Width) && (y >= 0 && y <= pictureBoxImageToCrop.Image.Size.Height))
        {
            var dr = DrawingRects.Last();
            if (dr.Rect.Width > 0 && dr.Rect.Height > 0)
            {
                rectImage = cropAtRect((Bitmap)pictureBoxImageToCrop.Image, dr.Rect);

                if (saveRectangles)
                {
                    count++;
                    rectangleName = GetNextName(Path.Combine(selectedPath, "Rectangle"), ".bmp");
                    FileList.Add($"{dr.Location}, {dr.Size}", rectangleName);
                    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                        FileList,
                        Formatting.Indented
                    );
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(selectedPath, "rectangles.txt"), false))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("Total number of rectangles: " + count + Environment.NewLine);
                        sw.Write(json);
                        sw.Close();
                    }

                    rectImage.Save(rectangleName);
                    saveRectanglesCounter++;
                }
                else
                {
                    var stream = ToMemoryStream(rectImage);
                    var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
                    pictureBoxCroppedImages.Image = image;
                }

                // Here I added an additional check to make sure the Image is set in pictureBoxCroppedImages
                if (saveRectangles && pictureBoxCroppedImages.Image == null)
                {
                    //pictureBoxCroppedImages.Image = rectImage;
                }

                pixelsCounter = rect.Width * rect.Height;
                pictureBoxCroppedImages.Invalidate();

                var newKey = $"{dr.Location}, {dr.Size}";
                var newItem = new MyListBoxItem
                {
                    Message = newKey + "," + FileList[newKey],
                    ItemColor = Color.Green
                };
                MyItems.Add(newItem);
                listBoxCroppedImages.SelectedIndex = MyItems.Count - 1;
                label2.Text = listBoxCroppedImages.Items.Count.ToString();

                pictureBoxImageToCrop.Focus();

                // Check if the image is null before using it
                if (pictureBoxCroppedImages.Image != null)
                {
                    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(this.pictureBoxCroppedImages.Image);
                    g.Clear(this.pictureBoxCroppedImages.BackColor);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (clearRectangles)
            {
                DrawingRects.Clear();
                pictureBoxImageToCrop.Invalidate();
            }

            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }
    }

    if (isRealTimeCropping)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

paint event:

```
private void pictureBoxImageToCrop_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (drawBorder)
    {
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, pictureBoxImageToCrop.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }

    if (pictureBoxImageToCrop.Image != null && selectedPath != null && DrawingRects.Count > 0)
    {
        DrawShapes(e.Graphics);
    }

    if (isRealTimeCropping)
    {
        // Draw cropping rectangle at cursor position
        Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(realTimeCursorPos.X, realTimeCursorPos.Y, cropRectWidth, cropRectHeight);
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, cropRect);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to keep the mouse cursor locked keep it inside the pictureBox area using mouse enter event.
This is just an example to show the idea, I did it with the pictureBox bounds and enter event, but it didn't work well. this is a wrong solution.

```
private void Form1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Clip = this.Bounds;
    }
```

Comment: It's difficult for me to know exactly what happened from your description，perhaps a gif or video would be helpful.

Comment: @shingo here is a link for a short video clip i recorded now showing the problem first I'm drawing the rectangles slowly then i move the mouse very fast so when the mouse cursor get out of the picturebox area the rectangle/s not always get to the edge of the picturebox in the direction i draw it.  my guess is that the mouse Api can't capture less then 20ms pixels speed I read about it somewhere.  not sure if this is the problem and not sure how to solve it.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAg24iW5yS0

Comment: This is expected behaviour, because the cursor is out of the area, the `MouseMove` event wont be fired. You need to listen the `MouseLeave` event, then you can use `Cursor.Position` to compute the position on the edge of the picturebox.

Comment: Just capture the mouse.